# Get stuck in the XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I made a simple html to play with XHR, but get no response from httpxml.responseText;
But the script does work in the safari console.

```
<html><head></head><body>
        <div id="myDiv"></div>
        <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function loadXMLDoc()
            {
            httpxml = new window.XMLHttpRequest;
            httpxml.open('GET','resources/xml/test.xml',true);
            httpxml.send();
            text = httpxml.responseText;
            alert(text);// there's no text in the alert window
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=text;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which book/tutorial did you read which made you to approach it wrongly?

Comment: @BalusC It's W3school Ajax tuts, I hesitated to learn the full test and miss the asynchronously point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the readyState test before.

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
  httpxml = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
  httpxml.open('GET','yourpage.xml',true);
  httpxml.send(null);
  httpxml.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(httpxml.readyState == 4) {
    text = httpxml.responseText;
    alert(text);
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=text;
    }
  }
}
```

But for this, I will use jquery, so easier :

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){ 
    $.GET('yourpage.xml',function(data){
      $('#mydiv').html(data); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm! and thanks pointing out the convenience jQuery version!

Comment: If it helps you and/or anyone, it's great ! And I find myself a lot of answers to my own script's bugs here.

Answer (score 2):

Is it just me or are you passing "true" as the third parameter of httpxml.open?  That means "perform the request asynchronously".  Either change this parameter to "false" or set a readystate callback function that gets invoked when the network operation has completed.

Better example code here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/

Comment: Good resources to learn, thanks for putting the official doc here